# creating a list of lists with a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm using an API to collect data on all 505 stocks in the S&P500. I have a list of all ticker names, but my API cant handle more than 25 stocks at once, so I'm trying to write a for loop that does so in batches.

So for example if my list is 
`list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
newlist=[]`

how do I use a for loop that creates n lists of 5 values, with the remainder also being added as a list (in this case the remainder is 2)?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
res = [list1[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(list1), 5)]

print(res)
```

Output:-

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12]]
```